# computation of the cross ratio

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, projective-geometry, cross-ratio

[image]

I was troubled by the definition of cross ratio,give four ordered points $X,A,B,Y$ the cross ratio should be $\frac{XB}{XY}/\frac{AB}{AY}$.But according to the bove definition in the screenshot,the cross ratio is $\frac{XB}{XA}\cdot \frac{AY}{BY}$. Where is wrong?

Comment: They won't agree as you set them up, since e.g. AB appears in the  "should be" but not in the "screen shot". Must at least use same four lengths. Also note the screen shot can be rewritten in several ways, involving ratio of two ratios istead of product.

Comment: The one that you wrote would give negative distances when $A$ is close to $B$. The one in the definition is for the points taken in the order $A,B,X,Y$.

Comment: @conditionalMethod，but in the screen shot,the order is $X,A,B,Y$?You mean that the cross ratio in the definition of the Hilbert metric is not the cross ratio of (X,A:B,Y)?

Comment: It is the cross ratio of $(A,B;X,Y)$, not for the order in which the points appear in the line. That one doesn't give a distance. Note that you can define cross ratios in any order you want, and all are projective invariants, although not all the permutations give the same value.

Comment: Thanks,I have another question.What's the meaning of projective invariants?

Comment: @conditionalMethod，the cross ratio of $(A,B;X,Y)$ is $ \frac{AX}{AY}/\frac{BX}{BY}$,it is not equal to $\frac{XB}{XA}\cdot \frac{AY}{BY}$ in the definition of the Hilbert metric.

Comment: Invariant by [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_fractional_transformation) transformations. Search for whichever permutation of the points gives the ratio in the definition. $(A,B;Y,X)$ maybe? More important is that the choice is such that you actually get a metric.

Comment: Would you mind showing the above definition is actually a metric? $d(A,B)\geq 0$ is obvious,but how to check $d(A,B)=d(B,A)$ and the triangle inequality?When we talk the cross ratio,the order is important,but according to the definition,I mistook it was the ratio of $X,A,B,Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix the order of symbols in the formula and the order of points along the line.

The points are in order $X,A,B,Y$ along the line, because $A,B$ are inside $\Omega$ while $X,Y$ lie on the boundary of $\Omega$. On the other hand, the order in the cross ratio formula is a different, if you follow typical conventions:

$$d(A,B)=\log\left\lvert\operatorname{CR}(Y,X;A,B)\right\rvert=\log\left(
\frac{\lvert YA\rvert\cdot\lvert XB\rvert}{\lvert YB\rvert\cdot\lvert XA\rvert}\right)$$

Let's look at a few special cases:

- $\lim_{B\to A}d(A,B)=\log 1=0$
- $\lim_{B\to Y}d(A,B)=“\log\lvert\infty\rvert”=+\infty$
- $\lim_{B\to X}d(A,B)=“\log 0”=-\infty$

So if you have the order as stated, with $B$ lying between $A$ and $Y$, then you get a cross ratio between $1$ and $\infty$ and a distance between $0$ and $\infty$ i.e. a positive distance. If on the other hand you were to change the order, so that $B$ lies between $X$ and $A$, then you'd get a logarithm less than $1$ and a negative distance. That's why the order of points along the line was specified the way it was.

Advanced use cases: For $B$ outside $\Omega$, i.e. order $X,A,Y,B$ you'd get a negative cross ratio, and a purely imaginary distance. (Writing the cross ratio using absolute value bars would be fairly confusing in this setup.) In some contexts this view might still make sense, to provide a more complete picture. In those situations you'd want to keep in mind that the imaginary part of a distance is no longer uniquely defined, since any multiple of $2\pi$ can be added to it to express the same cross ratio.