# Distance relation to $\ln (x)$

Tags: geometry, logarithms

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Suppose the points $A,B,C$ all lie on the line $\overrightarrow{PQ}$ and that $C$ has coordinate $0$. Suppose also that $A$ and $B$ have coordinates $a$ and $b$ respectively, given by
>
> $$a=-\left\lvert\ln\left(\frac{CP}{AP}\times\frac{AQ}{CQ}\right) \right\rvert, \quad b=-\left\lvert\ln\left(\frac{CP}{BP}\times\frac{BQ}{CQ}\right) \right\rvert.$$
>
> Show that under these conditions,
>
> $$\lvert a-b\rvert=d(A,B).$$

I have been able to simplify the $\ln$ to a quotient of $\frac{AQ}{BQ} \times \frac{BP}{AP}$ the following way:

Let

$$E=\frac{CP}{AP} \times \frac{AQ}{CQ} \quad F=\frac{CP}{BP} \times \frac{BQ}{CQ}$$

so that

$$a=-\lvert \ln E\rvert, \quad b=-\lvert \ln F\rvert.$$

Then

$$\lvert a-b\rvert = \lvert -\lvert \ln E\rvert - \lvert \ln F\rvert \rvert = \ln\left\lvert\frac{F}{E}\right\rvert = \ln\left\lvert\frac{CPBQ}{BPCQ}\times\frac{APCQ}{CPAQ}\right\rvert = \ln\left\lvert\frac{AP}{AQ}\times\frac{BQ}{BP}\right\rvert.$$

This is as far as I can go before I get stumped. I've been thinking it through but how does this relate to the distance between $A$ and $B$?

Comment: You should have a look to this question and its answer; https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3404202/305862. I Think you problem is that you **define** in this way a distance $d(A,B):=...$ but there is no connection with $|a-b|$...

Comment: Thank you and yes that is very helpful. This is clearly what the question is getting at and I’ll have a look. Much appreciated!

Comment: What is your definition of “coordinate”? And your definition of distance $d$? Since all of these can be defined in many ways, referring to your definitions will be important.